# Javascript: Insurance Program

Tags: javascript

Making a simple javascript program to classify users under certain insurance brackets depending on their age and marital status. The following program works, however when I test the program I cannot get the program to correctly differentiate between class 3 and class 4 insurance. Im fairly new to javascript so please excuse If I have something silly.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title> Insurance Program </title>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function insurance(form)
{

var fname = form.firstname.value;
var sname = form.surname.value;
var age = form.age.value;
var insurance;

var marital = form.maritalstatus.value;

document.write(marital);

if (marital = 2 && age >= 30)
{
insurance = "Grade 1";
}

else if (marital = 1 && age > 30)
{
insurance = "Grade 2";
}

else if (marital = 2 && age < 30)
{
insurance = "Grade 3";
}

else if (marital = 1 && age < 30)
{
insurance = "Grade 4";
}

document.write("Thank you " + fname + " " + sname + "<br>");
document.write("You belong to " + insurance + " Insurance");

}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<h4> Insurance Program </h4>

<form>
Enter your first-name : <input type = "text" name="firstname"> 
Enter your surname : <input type = "text" name="surname"> <br>
Enter your age: <input type = "text" name="age"> <br>
Select your current marital status
<Select id ="maritalstatus" name = "maritalstatus">
<option value = "1"> Single </option>
<option value = "2"> Married </option>
</Select>


<input type = "submit" value = "submit" onclick="insurance(this.form)">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

For one, you are using `=` when you should be using `===`. Example:

```
if (martial === 2 && age >= 30)
```

`martial = 2` and `martial = 1` are always going to be true so the last two else ifs are the same.

Reference: `=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) and `==` and `===` are [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYKEQ/15/):

```
if (parseInt(marital, 10) === 2 && parseInt(age, 10) >= 30) {
    ins = "Grade 1";
}
else if (parseInt(marital, 10) === 1 && parseInt(age, 10) >= 30) {
    ins = "Grade 2";
}
else if (parseInt(marital, 10) === 2 && parseInt(age, 10) < 30) {
    ins = "Grade 3";
}
else if (parseInt(marital, 10) === 1 && parseInt(age, 10) < 30) {
    ins = "Grade 4";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with every line that looks like this:

```
martial = 1 && ...
```

`marital = 1` sets `marital` to `1`. You want to *compare* `marital` to `1`, so use the double equals sign:

```
martial == 1 && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you misused `=` symbol in `if` operands, if you need compare values, use `==` or with `===` (for strict type checking)

Answer (score 0):

You should have '==' in your conditions

martial = 2 && age >= 30

martial == 2 && age >= 30

Because = is the assignment operator, and == is comparison.